# parsing integer in exponential notation from string

Tags: c++, string, integer, std

Apparently `std::stoi` does not accept strings representing integers in exponential notation, like `"1e3"` (= 1000). Is there an easy way to parse such a string into an integer? One would think that since this notation works in C++ source code, the standard library has a way to parse this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stod` (see [docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)) to do this, by parsing it as a double first.  **Be wary of precision issues when casting back though...**

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod

int main () {
   std::string text ("1e3");
   std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t
   double result = std::stod(text,&sz);
   std::cout << "The result is " << (int)result << std::endl; // outputs 1000
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: +1 but with reservations as (int)result is UB if the magnitude of result is too big.

Comment: Yup, I should emphasize that.

Answer (score 2):

> One would think that since this notation works in C++ source code, the standard library has a way to parse this.

The library and the compiler are unrelated. The reason this syntax works in C++ is that the language allows you to assign expressions of type `double` to integer variables:

```
int n = 1E3;
```

assigns a `double` expression (i.e. a numeric literal of type `double`) to an integer variable.

Knowing what's going on here you should be able to easily identify the function in the Standard C++ Library that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Emitting exponential notation into `std::stoi` would overflow too often and integer overflow in C++ is undefined behaviour.

You need to build your own where you can taylor the edge cases to your specific requirements.

I'd be inclined not to go along the `std::stod` route since a cast from a `double` to `int` is undefined behaviour if the integral part of the `double` cannot be represented by the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it as a double using standard streams, for example

```
double d;
std::cin >> d; //will read scientific notation properly
```

and then cast it to an int, but obviously double can represent far more values than int, so be careful about that.